# How to read input from Facebook Leadgen webhook in Laravel

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, laravel-5.4

The input looks like this:

```
public function webhook(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->input);
}

// output
[{
    "entry":[{
        "changes":[{
            "field":"leadgen",
            "value":{
                "ad_id":0,
                "form_id":724269564418666,
                "leadgen_id":8144548420666,
                "created_time":1502824666,
                "page_id":482428225170666,
                "adgroup_id":0
            }
        }],
        "id":"48242822517",
        "time":1502824702
    }],
    "object":"page"
}] 



$input[0]->entry[0]->changes[0]->value; // Undefined Offset 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The data Facebook is returning is in [JSON](http://json.org) format. You will need to use PHP's [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function to convert the data into a useable format, for example:

```
$entry = json_decode($request->input[0], true);
var_dump($entry[0]['changes'][0]['value']);
```

Comment: `json_decode($input[0], true) // undefined offset 0`

Comment: Ah, my bad, it should be `json_decode($request->input[0], true);` (Updated answer)